# for loop with substitution

Tags: vim, sed, substitution

I want to pass **for loop** as substitute command range:

`for i in range(x, y) | is/$/foo/ | endfor`

but i'm hit with `Trailing characters: foo/ | endfor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error reported by Vim is a bit misleading with regard to the actual problem in your command.

The actual problem is that the variable `i` can't be used like that. The whole substitution must be concatenated with `:help expr-..` and passed to `:help :execute`. In this case:

```
for i in range(x, y) | execute i .. 's/$/foo/' | endfor
```

If you don't do that, the `i` in `is/$/foo/` is interpreted as a literal `i` so the command you are using is `:help :isearch`, not `:help :s`. Vim thus reports a misuse of `:is` and completely—and rightfully—ignores your original intent.

Then there is another issue, not related to the problem at hand: `:help :s` already works on a range so there is no real need for a loop:

```
execute x .. ',' .. y .. 's/$/foo/'
```